# How to transform specific hierarchy tree to standard hierarchy tree

Tags: vba, excel

My users design folder tree in this format:
[image: Tree]

I would like transform this folder hierarchy to "Windows" format, like this:

- Root\Folder1\Folder11
- Root\Folder1\Folder12
- Root\Folder1\Folder13
  ....

So I did in VBA:

```
Sub GenerateTree()
   Dim Level1 As String
   Dim Level2 As String
   Dim Level3 As String

   Dim i As Integer
   Dim num_line As Integer
   Dim Result() As String
   ReDim Result(i)

   'Init
   Level1 = ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Value    

   'For each value    For num_line = 2 To 11
        If Len(ActiveSheet.Range("B" & num_line).Value) > 0 Then 'If cell Bx contains something
            Level2 = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & num_line).Value 'Update Level2
        End If
            Level3 = ActiveSheet.Range("C" & num_line).Value

        'Result(num_line - 2) = Level1 & "/" & Level2 & "/" & Level3
        ActiveSheet.Range("F" & num_line) = Level1 & "/" & Level2 & "/" & Level3
    Next num_line
```

But my result, isn't good. 
[image]

I have several problem, in my result:

- For `Root/Folder2/`, i have / at this end. I would like to have `Root/Folder2`
- I think, I need to add a function to know the max of `num_line`

Comment: Don't use IsNull to check whether a cell has content - something like `Len(ActiveSheet.Range("B" & num_line).Value)>0` will work

Comment: Thank i will update my code in my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The empty value is because `IsNull` will return `False` for any cell, as an empty cell will be interpreted as `""` or 0. Use `IsEmpty` or `cell.Value <> ""`.
Of course you shouldn't use that check with `Level3` because you want that to be empty sometimes.

2) To get rid of the trailing `/` you could simply check if `Level3` is empty

```
If Level3 <> "" Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("F" & num_line) = Level1 & "/" & Level2 & "/" & Level3
Else
    ActiveSheet.Range("F" & num_line) = Level1 & "/" & Level2
End If
```

3) There are many ways to find the last row. The easiest is

```
yoursheet.Cells(yoursheet.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
```

In your case you would have to check rows B and C and take the larger one.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

```
Sub GenerateTree()
   Dim Level1 As String
   Dim Level2 As String
   Dim Level3 As String

   Dim num_line_max As Integer
   Dim num_line As Integer
   Dim Result() As String
   ReDim Result(i)

   'Init
   Level1 = ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Value
   max_line_B = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
   max_line_C = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
   If max_line_B > max_line_C Then
      num_line_max = max_line_B
   Else
      num_line_max = max_line_C
   End If

   'For each value
   For num_line = 2 To num_line_max
        If Len(ActiveSheet.Range("B" & num_line).Value) > 0 Then 'If cell Bx contains something
            Level2 = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & num_line).Value 'Update Level2
        End If
            Level3 = ActiveSheet.Range("C" & num_line).Value

        If Level3 <> "" Then
            ActiveSheet.Range("F" & num_line) = Level1 & "/" & Level2 & "/" & Level3
        Else
            ActiveSheet.Range("F" & num_line) = Level1 & "/" & Level2
        End If
    Next num_line


End Sub
```